# How to fix the radio group doesn't affect other item in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

Here's the code

***list.component.html***

```
<form nz-form [formGroup]="taskFormGroup" (submit)="saveFormData()">
        <div nz-row *ngFor="let remark of checklis>
          <div nz-col nzXXl="12" *ngFor="let task of remark.tasks" style="padding: .5rem;">
<nz-form-item>
                  <nz-form-control>
                    <nz-radio-group formControlName="status" name="status" (ngModelChange)="onChangeStatus($event)">
                      <label nz-radio nzValue="true">Passed</label>
                      <label nz-radio nzValue="false">Failed</label>
                    </nz-radio-group>
                  </nz-form-control>
                </nz-form-item>

    <nz-form-item>
      <nz-form-control>
        <textarea nz-input placeholder="{{ remarkPlaceHolder }}" class="remarks-textarea" type="text"
          name="otherRemark"></textarea>
      </nz-form-control>
    </nz-form-item>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

***list.component.ts***

```
checklist = [
    {
      "id": "txv3vvBr8KYB",
      "assetType": {
        "id": "1fKBO4w0XHg7H",
        "code": "PRD",
        "name": "Printing1"
      },
      "tasks": [
        {
          "id": "1fKBO4w0XHg7H",
          "name": "Task 1",
          "description": "Check oil spill"
        },
        {
          "id": "ESOSA6aCrOER",
          "name": "Sample1",
          "description": "Desc1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "EwQciw9whx6B",
      "tasks": [
        {
          "id": "1nU7uASqfvLPD",
          "name": "TASK8888",
          "description": "DESC8888"
        },
        {
          "id": "EwQciw9whx6B",
          "name": "TASK9999",
          "description": "DESC9999"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

constructor (private fb: FormBuilder) {}


  onChangeStatus(event: any) {
    switch (event) {
      case true:
        this.otherRemark = '';
        this.remarkPlaceHolder = 'Remarks (optional)';
        break;
      case false:
        this.remarkPlaceHolder = 'Remarks (required)';
        break;
      default: break;
    }
  }
```

What I'm trying to do here, is to display the remarks (optional) or remarks (required) in textarea. if it passed it should display the remark (optional) in the textarea placeholder.

the problem is when I choose the passed or the failed it affect also the other item.

for the example there's two item

which is the

Sample 1 (item1)

Sample 2 (item2)

then I choose the passed on the Sample 1 then it display the remarks(optional) it also display on the Sample 2 textarea. How to fix it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make textboxes have different placeholder according to radio, you will need to manage flag which will monitor the change in respective radio.

**1. Populate flag array according to `checklist` data.**

```js
  textBoxStatus: string[][] = [];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.taskFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      remark: "",
      status: ["", [Validators.required]]
    });

    for (let parent of this.checklist) {
      this.textBoxStatus.push([]);
      for (let child of parent.tasks) {
        this.textBoxStatus[this.textBoxStatus.length - 1].push('false');
      }
    }
  }
```

**2. Setup html template to use this flag array**

```html
<form nz-form [formGroup]="taskFormGroup" (submit)="saveFormData()">
    <div nz-row *ngFor="let remark of checklist; let parent=index">
        <hr>
    Parent {{parent}}
        <hr>
        <div nz-col nzXXl="12" *ngFor="let task of remark.tasks; let child=index" style="padding: .5rem;">
            <hr>
      Child {{parent}}.{{child}}
      <hr>
            <nz-form-item>
                <nz-form-control>
                    <nz-radio-group formControlName="status" name="status" (ngModelChange)="onChangeStatus($event, parent, child)">
                        <label nz-radio nzValue="true">Passed</label>
                        <label nz-radio nzValue="false">Failed</label>
                    </nz-radio-group>
                </nz-form-control>
            </nz-form-item>

            <nz-form-item>
                <nz-form-control>
                    <textarea nz-input placeholder="{{ textBoxStatus[parent][child] == 'true' ? 'Remarks (optional)' : 'Remarks (required)' }}" class="remarks-textarea" type="text"
          name="otherRemark"></textarea>
                </nz-form-control>
            </nz-form-item>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**3. Change flags on action**

```js
onChangeStatus(event: string, parent: number, child: number) {
  this.textBoxStatus[parent][child] = event;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-start-qkkdtg)

Comment: yes, because there's a ```ngFor``` so there's multiple textarea and when I choose the passed the other textarea will affected to

Comment: I think this is what you need. If yes I ll explain it in answer https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-start-qkkdtg

Comment: what if you use observable https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-start-xz4c93?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: you stackblitz is broken. what is `select` here?